# variable that defined within a block

Tags: ruby

when Ruby executes the line `puts "#{number}..."`,
why it can’t know that the number there is supposed to be a variable?
It is trying to execute self.number method

```
class Roulette
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    person = name.to_s.capitalize
    3.times do
      number = rand(10) + 1
      puts "#{number}..."
    end
    "#{person} got a #{number}"
  end
end

number_of = Roulette.new
puts number_of.bob
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks in Ruby introduce a new lexical scope.

Therefore variables declared inside a block are local to the block's scope and cannot be accessed outside of it.

So the `number` variable only lives inside the block `3.times do ... end`.

As to what happens when your code executes:

When execution reaches the line `"#{person} got a #{number}"` Ruby will see that `number` does not exist as a local variable and then will try to call a method with that name. It will not find a method either so then it will execute the `method_missing` you defined.

Therefore you have kind-of a recursive function that will call itself indefinitely, so it will cause a `SystemStackError` exception.